# WL.Client.getLoginName("SingleStepAuthRealm") not getting in client side

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-studio, worklight-security

I am using Adapter-based authentication in hybrid application.

this is my adapter code

```
function submitAuthentication(username, password){
    WL.Logger.warn("Start intial---------------------");
    var input = {
            method : 'post',
            returnedContentType : 'json',   
            path : <path>,
            parameters : {
                <username> : username,
                <password> : password,   
            }
    };  
    var authResult = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);


    if(authResult.statusCode==200){
        WL.Logger.warn("Start-----------user id="+authResult.id);
        var userIdentity = {
            userId: authResult.id+"",
            displayName: username,
            isUserAuthenticated:1,
            attributes: {
                "firstName": authResult.firstName,
                "email": authResult.email,
                "role": authResult.authorities[0].authority,
            },
        };  
        WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", null);
        WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);
        return {
               authRequired: false

        };
    }else{
         return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
    }
    return authResult;
    }
```

Now i am facing an issue from the client side
Not getting the following value in the client side

```
WL.Client.getLoginName("SingleStepAuthRealm")
```

Any thoughts about this ?

Comment: which version of Worklight are you using? In your logs, can you confirm that the authentication was successful? What happens when you call getLoginName?

Comment: Also, try `getUserInfo` and see what you get (https://ibm.biz/BdEgZu)

Comment: Also - at what point do you try to call getLoginName? Are you sure the login process finished? (Please update your question with all this information - instead of replying here)